# count total number of list elements in pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `A` with column `keywords` as 
(here Im showing only 4 rows but in actual there are millions) :-

```
 keywords
 ['loans','mercedez','bugatti']
 ['trump','usa']
 ['galaxy','7s','canon','macbook']
 ['beiber','spiderman','marvels','ironmen']
```

I want to sum total number of list elements in column `keywords` and store it into some variable. Something like

```
total_sum=elements in keywords[0]+elements in keywords[1]+elements in 
          keywords[2]+elements in keywords[3]

total_sum=3+2+4+4
total_sum=13
```

How I can do it in pandas?

Comment: This really isn't clear to me. Please give a sample df (in code, so it's pre-built to save us time) and the expected output.

Comment: @roganjosh I have given a sample df as `A` and there is only one column in it as `keywords`. All I want to add all the list elements in columns `keywords` and store that value in variable named as `total_sum`

Comment: Mind provide the expected output ?

Comment: @Wen please check edited question.Hope you get it now :)

Answer (score 16):

IIUC

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['keywords']=[['loans','mercedez','bugatti'], 
                ['trump','usa'], 
                ['galaxy','7s','canon','macbook'], 
                ['beiber','spiderman','marvels','ironmen']]
```

Then juse use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and `sum`

```
df.keywords.str.len().sum()
```

---

Detail:

```
df.keywords.str.len()

0    3
1    2
2    4
3    4
Name: keywords, dtype: int64
```

---

Ps: If you have `strings` that look like a list, use `ast.literal_eval` to convert to list first.

```
df.keywords.transform(ast.literal_eval).str.len().sum()
```

Comment: I'm confused and sadly can't test, but why does `str.len()` count the number of elements in a list? That seems counter-intuitive

Comment: I'm gonna have to follow this up :) having this functionality as part of the `str` accessor has blown my mind a bit

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, it is not intuitive indeed. But `str.len` works differently depending on the type of object that is in that cell. It has different functionalities depending on if it is a dict, list, string or `np, nan` :) In the source code (and docstrings), you can see an example ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/strings.py#L2842)) of `str.len` in action with dicts, tuples, lists, ints and nans.

Comment: I appreciate this post, as simple as it was, it helped me with something that I was stuck on for a while now!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Using `sum` and `map`:

```
sum(map(len, df.keywords))
```

***Sample***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'keywords': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
})

sum(map(len, df.keywords))
```

```
12
```

***Timings***

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit sum(map(len, df.keywords))
1.87 ms ± 52.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.keywords.map(len).sum()
13.5 ms ± 661 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.keywords.str.len().sum()
14.3 ms ± 272 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

***Validation***

```
>>> sum(map(len, df.keywords)) == df.keywords.map(len).sum() == df.keywords.str.len().sum()
True
```

A bit of a disclaimer: using `pandas` methods on columns that contain lists is always going to be inefficient (which is why using non-pandas' methods is so much faster here), since DataFrames are not meant to store `list`.  You should try to avoid this whenever possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this one:

```
df.keywords.map(len).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that.

Maybe Pandas evolved since then.

```
df['len_of_list'] = df.my_columns_with_list.agg([len])
```

Cheers,

Comment: This is the only solution that counted the number of items correctly. Data format is as rafaelc described.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to sum total number of list elements in column keywords

This is different from what you pseudo-coded. I believe you mean to call the [size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) function for dataframes:

```
total_sum = keywords.size
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
len([item for sublist in df.keywords for item in sublist]
```

**Method 2:**

```
df.keywords.apply(len).sum()
```

.

```
df = [{"item": "a", "item_price": [1,1.5,2]}, {"item": "b", "item_price": [0.5,0.75,1]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
print("Ans:",len([item for sublist in df.item_price for item in sublist]))
```

**OUTPUT**

**df**

```
    item    item_price
0   a       [1, 1.5, 2]
1   b       [0.5, 0.75, 1]

Ans:6
```

Answer (score 0):

More like a list flatten problem

```
import itertools
len(list(itertools.chain(*df.keywords.values.tolist())))
Out[57]: 13
```